# Pulse Measurement of Heart Arrhythmia

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

In this challenge you have to make an ascii pulsing heart with rhythm problems (Heart arrhythmia) and then measure the pulse.Don't worry it's easy!

**Making the heart**

The heart alternates between these 2 states:
***state 1***

```
    ,d88b.d88b,
    88888888888
    `Y8888888Y'
      `Y888Y'
        `Y'
```

***state 2***

```
     d8b d8b
    888888888
    `Y88888P'     
     `Y888P'      
      `Y8P'
       `Y'
```

each step has **X seconds delay**
where X is a Random (Real) number between 0.3 and 1.4 (0.3<=X<=1.4)

**Measuring the Pulse**

When your arrhythmia-heart starts beating, you have to measure the pulse.
We want to know the heartbeats/min.
But (like many doctors do) you only have to count the heartbeats for 15 sec and then multiply by 4

**Final output**

Given no input, your code must run for 15 seconds (displaying the beating heart) and then **print the heart rate**.

Your output should look exactly like this!
(I will run my code 2 times for you to see the different results)

First example run:

[image]

Second example run:

[image]

you must output **one** heart
Good Luck!

this is code-golf
shortest answer in bytes wins!

Comment: Could you replace the two hearts with just 1? It makes the post more confusing

Comment: Should the output rate be computed from the pause times or from the actual running time (which will be slightly greater than the sum of pause times)?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing I've separated the figures to make it clear they are two independent runs

Comment: @LuisMendo Sorry I was afk.15 sec is the actual running time.Thanks for editing. I wanted to make sure that there is not a unique result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Mathematica, 212 bytes

```
g=",d88b.d88b,
88888888888
`Y8888888Y'
  `Y888Y'
    `Y'";h=" d8b d8b
888888888
`Y88888P'
 `Y888P'
  `Y8P'
   `Y'";t=1;TimeConstrained[Monitor[While[1<2,If[OddQ@t,b=g,b=h];Pause@RandomReal@{.3,1.4};t++],b],15];4t
```

Answer (score 3):

## Python [on Windows], 262 bytes

```py
from time import*
import os,random
t,i=time(),0
while time()-t<15:print([""",d88b.d88b,
88888888888
`Y8888888Y'
  `Y888Y'
    `Y'""",""" d8b d8b
888888888
`Y88888P'
 `Y888P'
  `Y8P'
   `Y'"""][i%2]);i+=1;sleep(random.randint(3,14)/10);os.system('cls')
print(i*4)
```

For linux and macOS use `os.system('clear')` for 2 more bytes.

Comment: You can xor `i` to save 2 bytes `[i%2];i+=1` becomes `[i];i^=1`

Comment: you have extra spaces after your second heart, i got it down to 262 bytes by removing them

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing I need `i` for `print(i*4)`

Comment: @micsthepick its missing some spaces, it results in one byte more actually

Comment: @FelipeNardiBatista thanks! fixed

Answer (score 0):

## Java, 374 bytes

```java
class G{public static void main(String[]a)throws Exception{long t=System.currentTimeMillis(),i=0;while(System.currentTimeMillis()<15000+t){p(",d88b.d88b,\n88888888888\n`Y8888888Y'\n  `Y888Y'\n    `Y'\n");Thread.sleep((long)(300+(Math.random()*1100)));i++;p(" d8b d8b\n888888888\n`Y88888P'\n `Y888P'\n  `Y8P'\n   `Y'\n");}p(i*4);}static<T>void p(T s){System.out.println(s);}}
```

Ungolfed:

```java
public class Golf {
    public static void main(String[]a)throws Exception {
        long t=System.currentTimeMillis(),i=0;
        while(System.currentTimeMillis()<15000+t) {
            p(",d88b.d88b,\n88888888888\n`Y8888888Y'\n  `Y888Y'\n    `Y'\n");
            Thread.sleep((long)(300+(Math.random()*1100)));
            i++;
            p(" d8b d8b\n888888888\n`Y88888P'\n `Y888P'\n  `Y8P'\n   `Y'\n");
        }
        p(i*4);
    }
    static<T>void p(T s){System.out.println(s);}
}
```